# TOC blank even after multiple compile

Tags: table-of-contents

I was working on a thesis (document class book) last month, and I had a draft prepared which was completely fine. The TOC, LOF and LOT all worked and showed up correctly. I also printed this draft out for corrections, and all was good on the print.

Today, I started working on the same thesis to employ the corrections I received. I did not change a thing in the code and compiled it twice (as mentioned many times over in this forum to compile at least twice to see the TOC, etc.) and the TOC, LOF and LOT did not show up. The rest of the document shows up perfectly fine with no errors. But the TOC, LOF and LOT are completely blank.

Ever since then, I've probably compiled it over 30 times and nothing has worked. The TOC, LOF and LOT are still blank. I see no errors in the log except for two new errors, which are -

> LaTeX Warning: Label `ta-1' multiply defined.
>
> LaTeX Warning: There were multiply-defined labels

The only thing I did differently was to update the packages and also update Texlive Utility. I have no idea what is going on. My code is long, and I don't know how much of it or what part of it I need to post here.

Is there any reason why this is happening? Any help is much appreciated.

```
System - Mac OS 10.14.3 (Updated since the last time I compiled the
document) 
Compiler - Texmaker
```

Comment: Prepare a very simple and small document that contains a table of contents and a few references. Does it work there?

Comment: Does deleting all temporary files like aux, toc, lot, lof etc and rerun LaTeX  help?

Comment: @Johannes_B yes it works fine with the smaller and simpler document.

Comment: @AndiW I have done this and it doesn't work, but I will keep trying and see how it goes. Further to this, I have been just running the compiler by editing few things in the document (more or less deleting something and running the compiler again and adding it back and running it again). This method seems to work as it brings the TOC, LOF, and LOT back up. But it vanishes again after further edits. It's really frustrating. But it looks like the only way to go for now.

Comment: You seem to introduce some error in the document with your edits.

Comment: @CornBlitz Adding a MWE to your question would help us a lot to help you...

Comment: I ended up rewriting the whole document bit by bit, and finally, I don't see the error anymore :)